# How to insert the inbuilt keywords in latex

Tags: verbatim, sourcecode

I am creating a simple tutorial file to take a seminar. My problem is: I want to get the output as "`\textbf` is used for making the font bold".  How can I get that? Likewise, i want to make this for some other keywords too, `\textit` and all the others...

If the problem is a `%` , i can use `\%` as well

But here, i want `\textbf` to be print in the `pdf`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use command `\verb##` and environment `verbatim` like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\verb#\textbf# is used to make the font bold, for example i could write:

\verb#\textbf{This Is Boldface!}#, resulting in \textbf{This Is Boldface!}

When you have multiple lines of code, it is best to use environment \verb#verbatim#:

\begin{verbatim}
\begin{verbatim}
\textbf{} %is used to make the font bold
\textbf{} %is used to make the font bold
\textbf{} %is used to make the font bold
\textbf{} %is used to make the font bold
\end{verbatim}\vskip-10pt
\verb#\end{verbatim}#

\end{document}
```

When you have multiple lines of code, it is best to use environment `verbatim`.

Answer (score 3):

It will be incomplete if `listings` is not mentioned for such a purpose.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{ %
  language={[LaTeX]TeX},
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    }
\begin{document}
  \lstinline{\textbf} is used to make the font \textbf{bold}

  \lstinline{\textit} is used to make the font \textit{italic}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

Hi! you can do:

\texttt{\textbackslash textbf} is used to make the font \textbf{bold}

\texttt{\textbackslash textit} is used to make the font \textit{italic}

or:

\textbackslash\texttt{textbf} is used to make the font \textbf{bold}

\textbackslash\texttt{textit} is used to make the font \textit{italic}

\end{document}
```

Hi! Take a look at this above: the simpler the better? I had this solution in my mind and, writing it down, I could appreciate it works with *no packages* (provided `T1` encoding is used, thanks to @egreg).

**Addendum:** if you plan to use it several times, then why not making a `newcommand`:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newcommand{\mact}[1]{\texttt{\textbackslash #1}}

\begin{document}

Hi again! you can just do:

\mact{textbf} is used to make the font \textbf{bold}

\mact{textit} is used to make the font \textit{italic}

\end{document}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Much better, of course, provided `T1` encoding is used.

Comment: @MattAllegro "it works with _no packages_". That is our swagger.